# Methyl vs halogen : order of precedence

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

[image: structure]
How would you name this compound?

4-bromo-2-methylpentan-3-one
**or**
2-bromo-4-methylpentan-3-one

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/68624

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be named as **2-bromo-4-methylpentan-3-one**

The alphabatical order should be followed while naming this compound. As **b** in bromo comes before **m** in methyl, it should be named as above.

See [here](http://www.chem.ucalgary.ca/courses/351/WebContent/orgnom/index.html) and [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/68632/39315) for more information.

Comment: Do halogen and alkyl group have the same priority? I was confused since my teacher said alkane comes before halide in the order of precedence.

Comment: It depends on the type of group present. For e.g. Between **ethyl** and **iodo**, ethyl will have more priority according to alphabatical order. See the links for more info.

Comment: @mettledmike Also see [this](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/27816/what-is-has-a-higher-priority-in-naming-organic-compounds-alkyl-groups-or-halid) answer.